# Where can a full stat block for Juiblex be found?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, planes

I'm playing a druid/planar shepherd attuned to the Abyss, and my character's reached epic levels. The DM's allowing my character to use the planar shepherd's augmented wild shape ability to assume the form of the demon lord Juiblex. However, I can only find a compressed and homebrew version of Juiblex's statistics and Juiblex's statistics for *Pathfinder*.

Can anyone help me find published *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* statistics for Juiblex?

Comment: Wait, your DM is letting you take the form of a Demon Lord? Wow. Um, given that it is a specific named character, and that it was introduced in a much earlier edition, it's entirely possible that it hasn't got official stats for 3.5rd edition. Do you want official stats only, or would homebrew (backed up with relevant user experience) be acceptable?

Comment: That's… *remarkably* generous of the DM. I'd be interested to know if, when transformed into the Faceless Lord, the DM also allows your PC to grant spells to Juiblex's  worshipers. (*Fiendish Compendium I* says, "Demon lords cannot grant spells, but the Abyss itself can, using the demon lords as conduits" (88), and now the PC's briefly an ersatz a demon lord!) That could be hilarious.

Comment: @GMJoe I am seeking official stats, technically. A homebrew adaptation that is based off of those stats, however, would be equally welcome. Also, the DM is going with RAW _"you become able to use wild shape to change into an elemental or outsider native to your chosen plane"_ -- Juiblex is an outsider native to my plane (Infinite Layers of the Abyss), so I can do so. Also, the spell-granting is an awesome concept, but I'll have to see with the DM. Even though I'm wild shaping into Juiblex, I'm not necessarily Juiblex himself...so I'm not sure how that will go over.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) statistics for a bunch of other demon lords, Wizards of the Coast's [*Fiendish Codex I: Hordes of the Abyss*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786939192) includes statistics for [Juiblex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_demon_lords_in_Dungeons_%26_Dragons#Juiblex) (66-68). The Faceless Lord has 21 Hit Dice.

Comment: Thanks! My DM has that book (one problem solved), but unfortunately I do not... :P I was trying to find an online resource for him for my own sake. Still, glad to know where to cite for my reference!